# ajax loader div not appearing on full screen while scrolling

Tags: php, css, jquery

I am using jquery ajax and i want to display loader `gif` image when ajax is working. The loader appears correctly, however when the user scrolls or resizes the window while the loader is showing the loader moves off the screen or changes in size. I would like the loader to be fixed full screen, so that even if the user scrolls, it will not disappear from view.

Here is my code of jquery

```
  jQuery.ajaxSetup({  
  beforeSend: function() {
     $('#loader').show();
  },
  complete: function(){     
     $('#loader').hide();
  },
  success: function() {}
});
```

and here is `CSS` of loader and its inner div

```
<style>
#loader
{
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=80);
    display:none;
}
#center {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px; // margin is -0.5 * dimension
    margin-left: -50px;
    z-index:5;
}



</style>
```

and html  is as follow

```
<div id="loader" >
    <div id="center">
        <img src="images/loading.gif" />
    <div>
</div>
```

and here you can check [my test page](http://sayhotel.com/rahul/ajax.php)

Comment: How does it appear for you? When I put your code into a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/aquzov/1) the wrapper div appears fullscreen, a little misaligned, but fullscreen.

Comment: i have mentioned my test link please check it

Comment: Your test link works perfectly for me, your ajax loader is both fullscreen and centered. What browser isn't it working in for you?

Comment: click on any above link will show you loader but its appear in upper portion only not on full screen , as far i undersstand the issue is that initally screen is small so its get 100% height width but data appearing using ajax so screen increase but its height width remain same thats the reason its appear that in upper part

Comment: I am using mozilla and its appears on all browser same ... check by scrolling when image loader is appear ...

Comment: If you scroll... then of course your going to be scrolling away from the div.. Do you mean to say you want to fix the div to the screen?

Comment: I want that div appears on full screen if i scroll down its should also appear there ...because below background is not appearing

Comment: -1 without any comment the worst thing i am facing on stackoverflow. If you don't have time to mention comment to improve question so you don't have rights to -1 the question.Your comment can improve the question quality but -1 only disappoint user like me without comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would roughly center the loader image both horizontally and vertically using your markup.

```
body { 
     height:100%;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
}

#center {
     width: 300px;
     height: 200px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 40%;
     left: 0px;
     width: 100%;
}

#loader {
     background-color: red;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     text-align:center;
     z-index: 1000;
     opacity: 0.5;
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=80);
}
​
```

Heres a jsbin, showing the result.

http://jsbin.com/owaciy/2/

** UPDATE **

By replacing `position:absolute` with `position:fixed`, you should be able to achieve the desired result:

http://jsbin.com/owaciy/3

Comment: thanks , position:fixed do exactly what i wants .  thanks once again